# How to add og tags to expo managed react native web app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

By default expo web build adds metadata description  `"A Neat Expo App"`  but not able to find any way to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be changed by using "description" property in your app.json

app.json

```
 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "name",
    ...
    "description": "Your app description",
    ...
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: How can I add og:image to this app.json?

Comment: You can edit index.html in web directory. @IKKA
See this: https://github.com/croma-app/croma-react/blob/master/web/index.html